# Use FBConnect to Share my app on Facebook

Tags: iphone, fbconnect

I am planning to do this simple thing:
create a button "Share on FacebooK" that open the Facebook login page and after the login there is a default message (to promote my App) that will be shared by my App on Facebook.

That sound stupid i know, but i only see examples with the user who can write a message and then share it on facebook, i don't want the user to interact, i just want the user share my App message on his facebook profile.

all i want is my App do something like this:

JACK WHITE "THISApp is the new app that bla bla bla etc etc bla bla bla etc etcbla bla bla etc etcbla bla bla etc etc the link is http/acme"

[THISApp icon] Today at 1pm via My Application Name

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well once you implement facebook connect , the user will be prompted to provide permissions for your app. You need to explicitly provide what permissions you need from the user. In your case post to wall. If the user allows your app, you will get a auth token which you can use in the background to post any message on to the users wall. This is fairly simple and doesn't need user interaction.

I assume you know how to get the authtoken other wise you can check the facebook book graph API integration tutorial by ray wenderlich. Developer.facebook.com has got the list of permissions and sample SDK hosted on github.

Comment: well i dont want to use this feature in the background, i want a simple "Share on Facebook" button in my App, but with the user unable to write something, he just post the message that i prepared like a standard message.

Comment: Offcourse its possible, all you need is the auth token and call the graph api to make the post with that auth token. In buttonclick event you compose your message and post it. There is no need to ask user for input. But first things first, you need the user to give permissions to your app and get the auth token.

Comment: That sound good, i just don't understand one thing: when the user clic on the button i suppose that he will need to login to facebook and then the auth page of facebook. Once he clic on the "authorize" button, what happend? there is a page with the message ready to be shared (but not modified) and a "cancel" button too?

Comment: No all you need is to get the auth token, he will be redirected to a page which you can specify or use the default one. The auth token is returned in case the user gives permission. Using this auth token you can publish your message. http://www.raywenderlich.com/1488/how-to-use-facebooks-new-graph-api-from-your-iphone-app

Answer (score 0):

Try using [MOFBHelper](http://mobileorchard.com/marketing-in-code-part-2-setting-a-users-status-in-facebook-from-an-iphone-app-a-tutorial/). Easy to use with minimal code.

This will set the user's status without the user having to type anything out. Hope that helps.